# Stripping text line with regular expression with c #

Tags: c#, regex

In the text shown below, I would need to extract the info in between the double quotes (The input is a text file)

```
Tag = "571EC002A-TD"

Tag = "571GI001-RUN"

Tag = "571GI001-TD"
```

The output should be,

```
571EC002A-TD

571GI001-RUN

571GI001-TD
```

How should I frame my regex in C# to match this and save it to a text file.

I was successful till reading all the lines into my code, but the regex gives me some undesirable values.

thanks and appreciate in advance.

Comment: Post the code for your regex

Comment: Actually, this seems to be doable with simple `Substring`

Comment: Downvotes to this question are allowed only for people with experience parsing large log files or using Splunk to do the same. Don't downvote what you don't understand

Comment: Which ***regex** gives me some undesirable values*? There is no regex in the question.

Comment: @Rakitić, your string should have been `string Tag = "Tag = \"571EC002A-TD\"";`. Also, that option is already posted in an answer.

Comment: oops! that was an unsaved one...thanks @Andrew... now the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rGSxeM) works :)

Comment: @Shans, did any of these help you?

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex could be:

```
Regex tagRegex = new Regex(@"Tag\s?=\s?""(.+?)""");
```

[Example with your input](http://rubular.com/r/Z6kXkAmIAE)

Comment: Why `+?`? If the string happens to have a `"` in the middle, it will stop there. Although that's not probably going to happen.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes in a regular expression. If you want to create a proper C# string you should escape both `\ ` and and `"`, ie `Tag\\s?=\\s?\"(.+?)\"`. Finally, you should explain that the OP can access the content through Match.Groups

Comment: OP wrote that he already tried some regex - so I assumed he is familiar with the usage.

Comment: Like @PanagiotisKanavos said, I think that last backslash can be removed, you are not escaping that because of the @ and you don't need to escape the double quote in a regex, like you are already not doing right before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

For those that ask why not use String.Substring: The great advantage of regular expressions over string operations is that they *don't* generate temporary strings untily you actually ask for a matched value. Matches and groups contain only indexes to the source string. This cane be a *huge* advantage when processing log files.

---

You can match the content of a tag using a regex like

```
Tag\s*=\s*"(<tagValue>.*?)"
```

The `?` in `.*?` results in a non-greedy search, ie only text up to the *first* double quote is extracted. Otherwise the pattern would match everything up to the last double quote.

`(<tagValue>.*?)` defines a named group. This way you can refer to the actual value captured by name and even use LINQ to process the values

The resulting C# code may look like this after escaping:

```
var myRegex=new Regex("Tag\\s*=\\s*\"(<tagValue>.*?)\"");
...
var tags=myRegex.Matches(someText)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(match=>match.Groups["tagValue"].Value);
```

The result is an IEnumerable with all tag values. You can convert it to an array or List using `ToArray()` or `ToList()` just like any other IEnumerable

The equivalent code using a loop would be

```
var myRegex=new Regex("Tag\\s*=\\s*\"(<tagValue>.*?)\"");
...
List<string> tagValues=new List<string>();
foreach(Match m in myRegex.Matches(someText))
{
    tagValues.Add(m.Groups["tagValue"].Value;
}
```

The LINQ version though can be extended very easily. For example, `File.ReadLines` returns an IEnumerable and doesn't wait to load everything in memory before returning. You could write something like:

```
var tags=File.ReadLines(myBigLog)
             .SelectMany(line=>myRegex.Matches(line))
             .OfType<Match>()
             .Select(match=>match.Groups["tagValue"].Value);
```

If the tag names changed, you could also capture the tag name. If eg tags have a `tag` prefix you could use the pattern:

```
(?<tagName>tag\w+)\s*=\s*"(<tagValue>.*?)"
```

And extract both tag name and value in the `Select` function, eg :

```
.Select(match=>new {
             TagName=match.Groups["tagName"].Value,
             Value=match.Groups["tagValue"].Value
});
```

Regex.Matches is thread safe which means you can create one static Regex object and use it repeatedly, or even use PLINQ to match multiple lines in parallel simply by adding `AsParallel()` before the call to `SelectMany`.

Comment: And do you think that all that `Regex` and LINQ do behind the scenes is **less** than generating one additional temporary string? Furthermore, code readability is very important and I honestly think all these options just obscure one's intentions.

Comment: @Andrew as I explained, no it doesn't. It generates only the final values, and only upon request. `Substring` won't even work if there are two or more tags per line or even an extra space. You'd require multiple string splits. As for readability, the various options expose *exactly* what ones intentions are - Select the tag value, or the tag and name value. This is more about familiarity than readability.

Comment: Well, OP didn't specify what other stuff can or cannot come in that file, so I assumed the format is what he posted. If the format changed, your regex may not work either, so there's no point in that discussion I think. Anyway I insist: look at your code, you worry about generating a string but use all that LINQ. And you are assuming OP needs a `List<string>`, which may not be the case. Don't get me wrong: your code is fine, but I find it illogical to worry about a string here. Only maybe if the file has 100K+ lines the substring option may use more resources.

Answer (score -1):

If those strings will **always** be like that, you can go for a simpler approach by just using `Substring`:

```
line.Substring(7, line.Length - 8)
```

That will give you your desired output.